# What rating Li-Po battery should I get for this configuration?

Tags: quadcopter, arduino, raspberry-pi, battery

I will have this configuration:

- A2212 Brushless Motor 1000KV - 4 each
- ECS - 30A Electronic Speed Control (ESC) - 4 each
- Propeller - 1045 Propeller CW & CCW Pair 10 inch * 4.5 pitch
- Arduino Mega - 2560 board
- Raspberry Pi 3
- Open pilot CC3D flight controller

I want to know what rating Li-Po battery should I get for this configuration.
The reason behind my asking here is because a simple google search is not able to satisfy me with an explanation...

Also, my weight will be 1.5 kg for the quadcopter, so I need a stable current discharge.

This is my first quadcopter, I am a Computer Science guy, so I have little knowledge of electronics, I'm learning, but need help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly its important to consider the worst case current draw by your motors. Since this determines how fast your battery will drain out. The size of the battery will be determined by its capacity and cell count. Generally bigger batteries like in laptops with their 4-cell 48Wh can power them up to an hour under intensive load. Which brings me to mention that one of the factors is how long do you want the quad to run. Though the laptop batteries run long, they are big in size so depending on the size of your quad, the battery size will have to be chosen. Again since, the battery adds weight, motors will draw more current, thus inline with the first point, determine the peak current draw of the entire system. I used motors since it draws the most. You can find more info on how to choose a LiPo battery [here](http://www.ultimaterc.com/forums/showthread.php?t=115264)

Comment: Also with this , it is very very very recommended to handle Li-po battery with extreme care and precautions if you dont want to burn your living room or whole house , never leave it unattended and always use 80% rule i.e never use more than 80% of the Li-Po battery on the drone , leave some energy on this Li-Po battery